# Installing OpenCV on Yosemite Mac

Tags: macos, opencv, homebrew

I am trying to install OpenCV on Yosemite using:

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install opencv
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Error: undefined method `deprecated_option' for Opencv:Class
Please report this bug:
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
/usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-science/opencv.rb:42:in `<class:Opencv>'
/usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-science/opencv.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:65:in `klass'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:50:in `get_formula'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:198:in `factory'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:12:in `block in formulae'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:12:in `map'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:12:in `formulae'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:27:in `install'
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:131:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone help resolve this?

Comment: StackOverflow is the wrong place for this report. Report it as a Homebrew bug by following the instructions on the web page linked in that error message after "Please report this bug:".

Comment: Please run `brew update`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to install different version, seems like this version has bugs with Yosemite.

**Try this**

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install opencv3
```

**Once installed try following command**

```
brew doctor 
brew update
```

And check this link for more help if you cant achieve to install, will help you to install from build.

http://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-3-on-yosemite-osx-10-10-x/

Answer (score 3):

update your homebrew

```
brew update
```